# How may I analyze percentage data with a Linear Mixed Model

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

I have conducted an experiment where several students assigned to two different groups had to solve 13 different puzzles each in two different sessions. Thus, we have 2 sessions, and two different tasks with 13 puzzles each are needed to be solved.

For example: if subjects solve 1 puzzle within a task, they completed 1/13 or 7.6% of the task, if they solved all puzzles, they have completed 100% of the task.

Then my dependent variable goes from 0 to 100% (100% of productivity if all puzzles are solved) in each of the sessions.

The data might look like this:
SUBJECT SESSION TASK PRODUCTIVITY 
1       1       2    20%
1       2       1    10%
2       1       1    50%
...

I heard that a **Linear Mixed Model (LMM)** considers that the dependent variable is not restricted between 0 and 100. Do you know how may I analyze those cases with a LMM?

May I use **nlme** or **lmer**?

Comment: Did each student get the same set of puzzles? If so, is the raw data (i.e. whether a puzzle was solved or not) available?

Comment: Yes to both questions